# Django: "Object is not iterable", when trying to modify said object

Tags: python, django, iterable

I am trying to edit an object ("Worry") which has been already created.

I have this code in views.py:

```
def worry_edit(request, id):
    worry = get_object_or_404(Worry, pk = id)
    original_pub_date = worry.pub_date
    form = WorryForm(request.POST or None, instance = worry)
    if form.is_valid():
        worry = form.save(commit = False)
        worry.pub_date = original_pub_date
        worry.save()
        return redirect(worry)
    return render_to_response('holaProy/worry_edit.html', {'worry_form': form, 'worry_id': id}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Which gives the following error when hitting the send button on the form:

```
argument of type 'Worry' is not iterable
```

Any insights on why that error is appearing and how to solve it?

Edit: As suggested by Girasquid, this is the complete traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/holaProy/worry_edit/1/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'holaProy',
 'registration',
 'django.contrib.humanize')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Richard\proyectosPython\holaProyecto\holaProyecto\holaProy\views.py" in worry_edit
  50.         return redirect(worry)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts\__init__.py" in redirect
  81.         if '/' not in to and '.' not in to:

Exception Type: TypeError at /holaProy/worry_edit/1/
Exception Value: argument of type 'Worry' is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you paste the full traceback?

Comment: Does the worry class have a get_absolute_url() method?

Comment: @girasquid you were right, I needed to add the get_absolue_url() method. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to to pass a model instance to `redirect`, you need to have defined a [`get_absolute_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method on it. Otherwise, Django just assumes it's a URL in string form and tries to parse it.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I didn't know about the function. Now it is working well.